# Is the Buddhist practice in The Kurosagi Corpse Delivery Service accurate?

Tags: kurosagi-corpse-delivery-service

In the manga series **The Kurosagi Corpse Delivery Service** ([wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Kurosagi_Corpse_Delivery_Service)) by Eiji Ōtsuka, the 5 main characters are young graduates from a Buddhist college (with special skills pertaining to the supernatural or to dead bodies.

I'm wondering how accurate the buddhist practices in the manga are to real life. There are a lot of supernatural elements to the story, but more specifically disposing and treatment of the dead, mantras/prayers, clothing, etc.

Does the series portray one sect/school of Buddhism more than others?

Comment: If it's on topic, it might be worthwhile to ask this question over at [Buddism SE](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/) as well. They have more expertise in this area afterall